# How to manage past and present tenses in cucumber-jvm

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

Using cucumber-jvm (or indeed any other BDD tools), how does one manage the use of past and present text?

For example:

```
Given that I have logged in as "admin"
And I have navigated to the "editor" page
When I drag an "image component" to my page
Then I see it appear
```

That's great, but then in further features, this becomes a precursor:

```
Background: 
  Given that I have logged in as "admin"
  And I am editing a page
  And I have added an "image component" to my page
```

...

So the actions are in fact identical, but there's two sets of domain language used.  How does one manage this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the actions are identical, you could use a non-capturing group in the step:

```
And /^I (?:drag|have added) an "image component" to my page$/ do
  # code
end
```